# How to add baseUrl (host) to Picasso via OkHttpClient Interceptor?

Tags: android, picasso, okhttp

I have object `Photo` with `String imageUrl = "foo.png"`

And have `String host = "http://example.com/photos/"`

I'm trying to load images with :

`mPicasso.load(photo.getImageUrl()).into(mImageView);`

```
public Picasso providesPicasso(OkHttp3Downloader okHttpDownloader) {
        return new Picasso.Builder(context).listener(new Picasso.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }).downloader(okHttpDownloader)
          .executor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())//avoid OutOfMemoryError
          .build();
    }

     public OkHttp3Downloader providesPicassoOkHttpClient(Context context) {
            File cacheDir = createDefaultCacheDir(context, BIG_CACHE_PATH);
            long cacheSize = calculateDiskCacheSize(cacheDir);
            OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .cache(new Cache(cacheDir, cacheSize))
                    .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                        @Override
                        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                            Request request = chain.request();
                            String host = "http://example.com/photos/";
                            HttpUrl newUrl = request.url().newBuilder().host(host + request.url()).build();

                            request = request.newBuilder().url(newUrl).build();
                            return chain.proceed(request);
                        }
                    })
                    .build();
            return new OkHttp3Downloader(okHttpClient);
        }
`
```

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unrecognized type of request: Request{foo.png}
03-01 14:06:49.856 19150-19150/com.basicflags W/System.err:     at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter$2.load(BitmapHunter.java:66)
03-01 14:06:49.856 19150-19150/com.basicflags W/System.err:     at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.hunt(BitmapHunter.java:206)
03-01 14:06:49.856 19150-19150/com.basicflags W/System.err:     at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.run(BitmapHunter.java:159)
03-01 14:06:49.856 19150-19150/com.basicflags W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
03-01 14:06:49.856 19150-19150/com.basicflags W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
03-01 14:06:49.856 19150-19150/com.basicflags W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
03-01 14:06:49.856 19150-19150/com.basicflags W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
03-01 14:06:49.856 19150-19150/com.basicflags W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Picasso rejects your request because it is trying to find suitable `RequestHandler` implementation based on the image URL. `NetworkRequestHandler` only accepts requests if `(SCHEME_HTTP.equals(scheme) || SCHEME_HTTPS.equals(scheme))` and will reject the request. So, if you want to reach your `Interceptor` I am afraid you will have to build the complete URL up front - adding a header shouldn't be a problem, then.

Comment: take a look at https://gist.github.com/swankjesse/8571a8207a5815cca1fb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that `Picasso` is rejecting your request because it does not recognize the type of `Request`. So there is no request to Intercept.

```
 W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unrecognized type of request: Request{img_fjords.jpg}
```

You should not transform your URL inside your `Interceptor` and should do that beforehand. You can add a [`Picasso.RequestTransformer`](http://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/com/squareup/picasso/Picasso.RequestTransformer.html) to your [`Picasso.Builder`](http://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/com/squareup/picasso/Picasso.Builder.html). As per documentation a `RequestTransformer` is:

> A transformer that is called immediately before every request is submitted. This can be used to modify any information about a request.
>   For example, if you use a CDN you can change the hostname for the image based on the current location of the user in order to get faster download speeds.

```
public Picasso providesPicasso(OkHttp3Downloader okHttpDownloader) {
    return new Picasso.Builder(context).listener(new Picasso.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    })
            .downloader(okHttpDownloader)
            .requestTransformer(new Picasso.RequestTransformer() {
                @Override
                public com.squareup.picasso.Request transformRequest(com.squareup.picasso.Request request) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "nonTransformedRequest: " + request.uri.toString());

                    String host = "https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/";
                    com.squareup.picasso.Request build = new com.squareup.picasso.Request.Builder(Uri.parse(host + request.uri.toString())).build();

                    Log.d(TAG, "transformedRequest: " + build.uri.toString());
                    return build;
                }
            })
            .executor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())//avoid OutOfMemoryError
            .build();
}
```

And you can handle the rest in your `Interceptor`

```
public OkHttp3Downloader providesPicassoOkHttpClient(Context context) {
        File cacheDir = createDefaultCacheDir(context, BIG_CACHE_PATH);
        long cacheSize = calculateDiskCacheSize(cacheDir);
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .cache(new Cache(cacheDir, cacheSize))
                .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                    @Override
                    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                        Request request = chain.request();
                        Log.d(TAG, "URL in Interceptor: "+request.url());
                        request = request.newBuilder().build();  //ADD HEADERS HERE
                        return chain.proceed(request);
                    }
                })
                .build();
        return new OkHttp3Downloader(okHttpClient);
    }
```

Now just use your `mPicasso` as intended

```
mPicasso.load(photo.getImageUrl()).into(mImageView);
```

Here is how our `LOG` looks

```
02-15 15:10:14.767 6531-6531/com.smk.stack D/TAG: nonTransformedRequest: img_fjords.jpg
02-15 15:10:14.767 6531-6531/com.smk.stack D/TAG: transformedRequest: https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_fjords.jpg
02-15 15:10:14.828 6531-6590/com.smk.stack D/TAG: URL in Interceptor: https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_fjords.jpg
```

Comment: Need to use `request = request.buildUpon().setUri(Uri.parse(host + request.uri.toString())).build();` to avoid lost of transformations

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can try concat base url with photo url of each photo.

```
public static final String BASE_IMAGE_URL = "//your image host"

...

Picasso.with(getContext()).load(BASE_IMAGE_URL + "image url").into(your imageview);
```

Comment: Yes , it can be like it, but I need also add headers to request

Answer (score 2):

first of all, you can add headers to your request via Interceptors.

```
 private Interceptor getDefaultHeaderInterceptor() throws IOException {
        return new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request.Builder requestBuilder = chain.request().newBuilder();
                requestBuilder.header(ApiConstants.ACCEPT_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
                requestBuilder.header(ApiConstants.AUTHORIZATION, oauthTokenStore.getAccessToken());
                return chain.proceed(requestBuilder.build());
            }
        };
    }
```

Than you can create the OkHttpClient like this.

```
public OkHttpClient getOkHttpClient() throws IOException {
         OkhttpClient.Builder builder = new Builder()
                        .readTimeout(BuildConfig.CONNECTION_READ_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .connectTimeout(BuildConfig.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .addInterceptor(getDefaultHeaderInterceptor())
                        .build();
```

...
and finally construct the Picasso instance:

```
public Picasso providePicasso() {
        return new Picasso.Builder(context)
                .downloader(new OkHttp3Downloader(getOkHttpClient()))
                .build();
    }
```

then you can use it like @faranjit told you:

```
providePicasso().load(BASE_IMAGE_URL + "image url").into(your imageview);
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple! You have a class `Photo`? Add a method

```
public String getFullUrl(Context context) {
  return context.getString(R.string.host) + imageUrl;
}
```

to it, move your host definition into string resources (bonus: you can override it for different configurations now e.g. for staging, production etc.).

If you need additional headers, add them in an `Interceptor`. For the Picasso use the new method:

```
mPicasso.load(photo.getFullUrl(getContext())).into(mImageView);
```